# How to Extract link from a sentence in google document with appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, document

I have a table in google doc, in which I want to extract the hyperlinked text and its link using appscript

Suppose : The community is here to help you with specific [coding](https://google.com), algorithm, or language problems.

I have a code for google spreadsheet which can extract links from the text, however the same code is not usuable in google docs.

```
 function myFunction() {
 var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var isCell4Blank1 = sheet.getRange("A1").isBlank();


        if (!isCell4Blank1) {

            var linkData = sheet.getRange("A1").getRichTextValue().getRuns().reduce((ar, e) => {

                var url = e.getLinkUrl();
                Logger.log(url);
                if (url) {
                    var color = e.getTextStyle().getForegroundColor();
                    var startIndex = e.getStartIndex();
                    var endIndex = e.getEndIndex();
                    var text = e.getText()
                    //ar.push(color);
                    ar.push(text);
                    ar.push(startIndex);
                    ar.push(endIndex);
                    //ar.push(url);
                }
                return ar;
            }, [])
 }
 }
```

How to modify it for google docs ?

Comment: Could you clarify how is your code not usable? Are there any errors or you can't get the desired result?

Comment: this code is running in googlesheet, i want to modify it to run with google document app